# Running Zoom in parallel to another resource-heavy program

Tags: windows-10, performance, unity3d, zoom-meeting

I teach a course on game development in Unity 3D. Due to COVID-19 the teaching is done remotely using Zoom. While teaching, when I click the "Play" button of Unity, it works hard and takes most of my computer's resources (it's resource-heavy). As a result, the sound quality is bad, and the students complain that my voice is "fragmented".

My question is: can I, in Windows 10, somehow divide the resources between Unity and Zoom, so that Zoom is guaranteed a fixed portion of the CPU and is not affected by Unity?

(I work on Dell XPS 9570, if that matters).

Comment: I have one idea.. something I would try if this were me.  Run zoom/you on one machine.. run zoom/debugger/unity/etc on another as another zoom instance.  Also.. reduce startup items and services you aren't using.

Comment: Good idea, but it requires two different machines, and both of them should be strong in order to run Zoom. So it is quite expensive.

Comment: I have a crappy 10 year old budget HP laptop that is able to run zoom with NO PROBLEM.  OLD OLD core i5.  4gb ram.  Also.. I ran it just the other day with a SUPER cheapie home-built 15 year old AMD Athlon + 4gb on windows 7 with a chepie web cam.  People on the other side said that it was great. FYI.. And good luck!  Thanks for teaching our craft!